# Linked List Help, Singly Linked (Multiple Structures) (C Programming)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, structure

I need some help with Linked Lists.
I have figured out how to do individual linked list, but I am struggling when trying to implement multiple struct's and lists.

My last program was all used with Structs but now I must implement linked list's.
It says to use "External Pointers" in the functions to use in traversing through the various lists.

This is homework for one of my classes, I am not asking for you all to do it for me, but I am asking to help point me in the right direction.

The structs are as follows:

```
            struct stockItem
            {
              char stockName[60];
              char stockType[60];
              int itemNumber;
              float actualCost;
              float markUp;
              int totalCurrentInventory;
              int monthlyRestock;
              float price; //stores actual cost + markup

            };


            struct roomData
            {
              float widthFeet, widthInch;
              float lengthFeet, lengthInch;
              char roomName[100];
              int roomNumberOfType;
              char roomType[6]; //char of room type
              int roomStock[100][2]; //for storing each room stock types
              int roomHasStock; //if the room has a stock avaliable
              int roomStockCount; //how many stocks the room has
              float area;  // sq ft
              float rentalRate;
              float profitsPerRoom;
              float netProfit;
              float grossProfit;
              char stockLine[200];
            };

            struct staffData
            {
                char firstName[100];
                char lastName[100];
                char fullName[100];
                int employeeNumber;
                char typeOfEmployee[10];
                char payType[10];
                float hourlyWage;
                float salary;
                int hours;
                char address[150];
                char city[150];
                char state[10];
                int zip;
                char phone[30];
                float yearlyTotalPay;

                struct hireDate //holds staff hire date
                {
                  int month;
                  int day;
                  int year;
                }hireDate;

                struct birthDate //holds staff birth date
                {
                  int month;
                  int day;
                  int year;
                }birthDate;
            };
```

Comment: You're going to need to be more descriptive.  What do you mean by "multiple struct's and lists"?  What is meant by "external pointers"?  You should probably just post the actual text of the assignment. (unless that would get you in trouble)

Comment: So are you asking how to handle these structs in the node of a linked list?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct YourStructNode_ {

   struct YourStructNode_ * next;
   struct YourStructNode_ * prev;

   YourStruct data;

} T_YourStructList;
```

Replace "YourStruct" by the name of your structs to make a doubly linked list.

Even if you make more than once T_XXXX_List with this pattern you should manipulate the list with the same function since the two first fields of T_Node is always the same.

Write add, insert, remove functions to manipulate this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Is your linked list supposed to utilize the structs that you have developed? This way you have a linked list where each node contains an instance of all of those structs you listed.

```
struct node {
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  roomData room;
  stockItem stock;
  staffData staff;
  hireDate hire;
  birthDate birth;  
};
```